# Error escaping char in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove every occurences of \uXXXX in a (badly encoded) string, but I keep getting the following error :

> raise source.error("incomplete escape %s" % escape, len(escape))
>   sre_constants.error: incomplete escape \u at position 0

So I was trying to replicate in the console python3.5.2:

```
s = '\u2000'
s = re.sub('\\u(.){4}', '', s)
```

Gives me the same error. So I tried to add the r' but it doesnt do anything then :

```
>>> s = re.sub(r'\\u(.){4}', '', s)
>>> s
'\u2000'
```

which makes sens since it tries to match '\u' now.

but when I try :

```
s = '\u2000'
s = re.sub(r'\u(.){4}', '', s)
```

I get the error as well.

I think my regex is ok, at least it works on : https://regex101.com/

What did I miss ?

Regards

Comment: try assigning `s` as `s = r'\u2000'`.

Comment: `s` is a single character with unicode code point 2000. Your regex searching for a backslash, a `u` character and 4 digits won't match `s`.

Comment: @sardok >>> s = r'\u2000'
>>> s=re.sub('\\u(.){4}', '', s)
Same exact error

Comment: Of course it throws the same error. Try the other regex.

Comment: @Aran-Fey when I assign '\u2000 blabla' to s, I get the exact same error, also s is a str object no ?

Comment: It's almost like the error is coming from your regex pattern, not the input string.

Comment: Try this @Maxime, `re.sub(r'\\u(.){4}', '', r'\u2000')`.

Comment: @sardok thanks it works !

Comment: Where does this string come from? Can you show us its representation? `s = '\u2000'` shouldn't have any encoding problems, it's the same as writing `s = " "`. If your original string contains literal escape sequences then that's a different story.

Comment: @mata These strings come from a badly encoded json, so i'm stuck with this kind of strings : '\u00c3\u00a9go\u00c3\u00afste' and I'd like to know how I can parse this with regexes to have something readable. I dont want to use ftfy to fix the caracters since a lot of them are smileys which I dont want to display anyway.

Answer (score -1):

There is another quick way in python to achieve the same it seems you are trying to remove all the `unicode` character hence the workover is to keep only `ascii` character in string as below:

```
s = '\u2000'
s = s.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
```